# PLSQL Return Sequence.currval When Sequence Name Is Built Using Substitution Strings

Tags: plsql

I would like to use the same application in different instances so I need to specify the workspace and sequence ID.

Example query

```
BEGIN
INSERT INTO STEP (STEP_CHART_TITLE)
VALUES ('Action', 'Action');
RETURN '"'||:v_workspace||'"."'||:v_seqid||'".currval';
END;
```

If I use:

```
"FREEADMIN"."ISEQ$$_111997".currval;
```

in the return statement it works fine.

If I use the substitution strings, it will build the string correctly, but won't return the sequence number.

Is there a way to get the sequence number?

Thanks

Comment: i would assign it to a variable then return the variable. Building string with return may show crooked behavior

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"PL/SQL" as **Oracle**'s procedural extension to SQL? Asking because I don't quite understand what "workspace" represents (we call it a "user" or a "schema" or even "owner" in Oracle).

If so, then you can't fetch current value unless you first fetch next sequence value (you didn't post whole code you use so I'm not sure whether you did that or not; also, `insert` statement is wrong - you're inserting 2 values into a single column).

```
SQL> select seq.currval from dual;
select seq.currval from dual
       *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-08002: sequence SEQ.CURRVAL is not yet defined in this session


SQL> select seq.nextval from dual;

   NEXTVAL
----------
         6

SQL> select seq.currval from dual;

   CURRVAL
----------
         6

SQL>
```

---

Therefore, the whole code might look like this - you'd use dynamic SQL. As this is SQL*Plus, I'm using substitution variables; you'd use bind variables (i.e. `:v_workspace` instead of `'&v_workspace'`) (if that's what you're doing). This code just displays the value - you'd `return` it.

```
SQL> create table step (id number, step_chart_title varchar2(10));

Table created.

SQL> declare
  2    l_str varchar2(200);
  3    l_id  number;
  4  begin
  5    l_str := 'select ' || '&v_workspace' ||'.'|| '&v_seqid' ||'.nextval from dual';
  6    execute immediate l_str into l_id;
  7
  8    insert into step (id, step_chart_title) values (l_id, 'Action');
  9
 10    dbms_output.put_line(l_id);    --> L_ID now contains CURRVAL
 11  end;
 12  /
Enter value for v_workspace: scott
Enter value for v_seqid: seq
8                                     --> here it is

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!   Thanks for the quick and accurate response.